# jQuery: use variable for td:eq

Tags: jquery, find, calculated-columns, dynamic-columns

I am using the below function to filter a table based on an input field which is working fine.

Currently this is referring to a fixed column index where I say " `'td:eq(3)'` ".

How can I refer to my variable "colIndex" here instead of using a fixed column index ?
Also, is there a way I can get the id of the current table based on my first code line so that I dont have to refer to a table class ("myTable") below ?

**My code (working):**

```
$('.myClass').on('keyup', function () {
    var colIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();
    var regex = new RegExp($(this).val().toLowerCase(), "i");
    $('.myTable').find('tr:gt(1)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('td:eq(3)').text().match(regex) == null) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concatenate it into the string that is the selector like this :

```
$(this).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')')
```

giving you

```
$('.myClass').on('keyup', function () {
    var colIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();
    var regex = new RegExp($(this).val().toLowerCase(), "i");

    $('.myTable').find('tr:gt(1)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')').text().match(regex) == null) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

it seems easier to do something like :

```
$('.myClass').on('keyup', function () {
    var idx = $(this).closest('th').index(),
        val = this.value.toLowerCase();

    $('.myTable tr:gt(1)').css('display', function() {
        return $('td', this).eq(idx).text().toLowerCase() == val ? 'block' : 'hide';
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is perfect. I'll try out the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use string concatenation

```
$('.myClass').on('keyup', function () {
    var colIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();
    var regex = new RegExp($(this).val().toLowerCase(), "i");
    $('.myTable').find('tr:gt(1)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')').text().match(regex) == null) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

or my preferred way is to use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq)

```
$('.myClass').on('keyup', function () {
    var colIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();
    var regex = new RegExp($(this).val().toLowerCase(), "i");
    $('.myTable').find('tr:gt(1)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('td').eq(colIndex).text().match(regex) == null) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Some changes you can try out are

```
var $table = $('.myTable');
$('.myClass').on('keyup', function () {
    var colIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();
    var regex = new RegExp($(this).val().toLowerCase(), "i");
    $table.find('tr').slice(1).each(function () {
        $(this).toggle(regex.test($(this).find('td').eq(colIndex).text()));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - i'll try this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way available to do this, That is by using `nth-child` selector. But there is a small difference between the `:eq` and `:nth-selector`. That is `:eq` prefer lower bound as `0` but at the same time `:nth-child` prefers lower bound as `1`.

```
$('.myClass').on('keyup', function () {
    var colIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();
    var regex = new RegExp($(this).val().toLowerCase(), "i");
    $('.myTable').find('tr:gt(1)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('td:nth-child(' + (colIndex + 1) + ')').text().match(regex) == null) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```